# Using onActivityResult() to start new Activity

Tags: android

Can the method `onActivityResult()` be used to start new activity?

What I am trying to do is that I have 3 activities: A, B, C

I start activity B for Result from A and after its done results are returned to Activity A to the method `onActivityResult()`. Here based on the returned result I want to start either activity B again or Activity C. Can it be done? How can I do it? I tried to do it in usual way using intents but It didn't work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use to start Either ActivityB or ActivityC. For instace:

```
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      Intent toStart = null;
      switch(resultCode) {
          case RESULT_CODE_B:
                // create ActivityB intent
          break;

           case RESULT_CODE_C:
                // create ActivityC intent
          break;          

         default:
             break;
      }   

      if (toStart != null)
            startActivity(ActivityA.this, toStart);
}
```

Comment: I tried to do this but the problem is that the new activity doesn't start I don't know why it gives no error just stay on the same activity in which the onActivityResult() method is present!

Comment: Thank-You for your help I got it solved was having problem in the Activity C!